# Xcode: No such module "Kolada"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use this framework called Kolada (https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda), but when I add in my podfile 'pod Kolada', then import Kolada, then build, I get an error `No such module "Kolada"`.

Has anyone used this module recently and has had the same issue? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What's your Podfile look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project, remove derived data, run 'pod deintegrate', then run 'pod install'

Comment: When I do that, I get an error: [!] Unable to find a specification for `Kolada`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: The Pod is "Koloda", not "Kolada"

Answer (score 0):

You need to run install the pod using the terminal on the project directory to be able to import a framework in the podfile.

```
pod install
```